# Netty server for many long-lived TCP connections

Tags: netty, tcp

I'm porting some TCP server/client code to Netty.

One question, the server will handle long-lived connections from many clients.  I don't currently need and most likely won't need to do things like broadcast to all clients in a batch operations etc... but I just need a storage place for these channels and a mechanism that allows me to selectively send notifications down to the clients given some client ID.

My question is is a ChannelGroup an acceptable mechanism to hold these channels?  When I first get a connection I will store the channel's ID with the client ID in a lookup map so that whenever I need to notify a particular client I will look up the channel ID I need to write to and then grap that Channel from the ChannelGroup and only send a message to that channel.

Anything wrong with that approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that seems reasonable, although I would just store the Channel with the client id, and possibly attach a listener to Channel#getCloseFuture() in order to maintain my mappings. However, a ChannelGroup is still useful, especially for closing "associated" channels as a unit.

Comment: Hey, So I ended up extending DefaultChannelGroup so I can internalize the mapping of the "device id" to the "channel id" and do things like getChannelByDeviceId with ease.  I haven't finalized hooking it up yet but I'll let you know when it's done.